# Export regression results to a Word file

Tags: r, export, regression

I'm trying to export my regression result (OLS) to a Word file.

I tried this code:

```
library(jtools)
export_summs(regression_1, regression_2, scale=TRUE, to.file = "docx", file.name = "regression_results")
```

but I got this error message:

```
Error in delete_cols(x, idx) : Tried to delete a non-existent column
```

How can I export the result of one or more regressions into a Word file (with the same results that I get from the summary function)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please can you include minimal data and code to reproduce your issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For what it is worth, I would also have a look at the packages `texreg` and `stargazer`.

Comment: `gtsummary` is another package worth looking into

Comment: You should contact the package `jtools` maintainer. I cannot get a simple example to work either for pdf or docx, but html works. I suspect you must have MS Word installed. The error message for pdf indicates that pdflatex must be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably sorted this out already, but I got it to work for me:
(1) I installed the package `flextable` and (2) used the following code:

```
install.packages("flextable")
flextable::export_summs(modelo_temp, scale = F, digits = 4, 
                        to.file = "docx", file.name = "regression_result.docx")
```

R created a dox file called `regression_results.docx` in my working folder.